# Surface area of convex vs. non-convex polyhedra with same volume

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

How can I show that for a given volume, a convex orthogonal polyhedron will have a smaller surface area than a nonconvex orthogonal polyhedron?

If this is not possible to show, can it be shown that a cube will have a smaller surface area than any other orthogonal polyhedron, convex or nonconvex, of the same volume?  How?

Comment: Why does this have the algebraic-geometry tag?

Comment: You can't.  Counterexample:  Cube vs. Sphere with a small dent in it.

Comment: What is true is: for any nonconvex polyhedron, there exists a convex polyhedron with the same volume and smaller surface area. 

Comment: Um, for *every* polyhedron (i.e. even convex one), there exists a convex polyhedron with the same volume and smaller surface area.

Comment: Of course, but the difficult reduction is from nonconvex to convex (because it requires non local variations).

Comment: If you pick a point inside the polyhedron from which it does not look star-like, and you replace the polyhedron with a star-like figure with that center with the same mass in each direction, does that reduce the surface area? Unfortunately, the result is not necessarily convex, and not necessarily a polyhedron, but perhaps if you start with a polyhedron some finite sequence of these would produce a convex figure.

Comment: Difficult reduction? Won't taking the convex closure of the non-convex polyhedron suffice?

Comment: I have edited the question based on the comments.
Can anyone suggest an appropriate tag?

Comment: What is an "orthogonal" polyhedron?  One whose faces are all parallel to a coordinate plane?

Comment: "An orthogonal polyhedron is one all of whose faces meet at right angles, and all of whose edges are parallel to axes of a Cartesian coordinate system."  [wikipedia.org]

Comment: @Dima: no, consider the catenoid (approximated by a polyhedron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both questions have affirmative answer.

Let $S⊂\mathbb R^3$, and $S_1,S_2,S_3⊂\mathbb R^2$ the projections planes $xy$, $yz$ and $xz$ of $S$ it is known that
$$V(S)^2≤A(S_1)A(S_2)A(S_3)$$

This also follows from the first inequality in this text
http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~ehudf/docs/KKLBKKKL.pdf using the indicators functions of $S_1$,$S_2$ and $S_3$.

Now using this inequality we will prove that the cube has the least surface area.
Given $S\subset\mathbb R^3$ we can construct a box $B$ with projection $B_1,B_2,B_3$ such that $A(S_i)=A(B_i)$ just by taking the box with sides $$\sqrt{ A(S_i)A(S_j)/A(S_k)}$$ for  $i,j,k=1,2,3$ all different. Since for the box the inequality becomes equality it follows that $V(S)\leq V(B)$. Now take an orthogonal polyhedron $P$ and let $A(P)$ its surface area, then crearly $$A(P)\geq 2(A(P_1)+A(P_2)+A(P_3)),$$ then if we take the box with $A(B_i)=A(P_i)$ it follows that $A(B)=2(A(P_1)+A(P_2)+A(P_3))\leq A(P)$ therefore
$B$ increases the volume and decreases the surface area.
Finally it is an easy calculus exercise that from all the boxes with fixed volume, the one with less surface area is the cube.